# If the bisectors of three interior angles of a convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ intersect at a point $P$, then $P$ is also on the fourth interior bisector.

Tags: geometry

> Show that if the bisectors of three interior angles of a convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ intersect at a point $P$, then $P$ is also on the fourth interior bisector.

Need to solve it fast, it's really important it might sound as a elementary problem but yeah :) And I tried to do it with angles but it didn't work out well.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects problems contain something of what the asker knows of a problem. (What have you tried? etc.) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve your understanding, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) In the problem at hand: Are you aware of how to prove that the angle bisectors of a triangle meet at a point?

Comment: I tried to do it with angles but it didnt work :(

Comment: [Edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3364961/edit) (since comments are easily overlooked) to show what you tried, and perhaps someone can help you adjust your argument.

Comment: Did it, thanks, do u have any idea what shoud i try more or how to solve this problem?

Comment: "I tried to do it with angles" tells me almost-nothing, so it's hard to suggest what "more" you could do. *What did you try?* and *With what angles?* ... My advice is in my first comment, which I'll restate as a hint: *Think about the standard proof that the angle bisectors of a triangle meet at a point.*

Comment: Can u give me atleast a hint or any specific properties of convex quadrilateral that might help me?

Comment: Put very briefly:  draw perpendiculars to all sides from $P$.  Using the known angle bisectiobs use HA to prove various airs of triangles congruent.  This forces all the perpendicular segments to be congruent.  Now move to the vertex with the "unknown" bisector.  The two triangles there are proven congruent by HL causing t hff e vertex angle to be split exactly in half.  Details are left for you.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I have drawn it and i can see that all of those segments are congruent but i cant find the way how to get the segment of "unknown" bisector and how to prove that they are equal... could u please writte me steps or show me ur drawing if u have time. I can send my drawing if u want to see if i drew it right

Comment: Let D be the unknown vertex.  PD is the common hypoteneuse of two right triangles in which you know a pair of congruent legs (the perpendiculars to the sides), thus HL.  The angle congruence you want will come from corresponding parts.

Comment: Oh i got it since i have angle that is 180- alfa- beta -gama on both sides

Comment: Thanks again I was so blind 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a trigonometric proof:

Let PA, PB and PC be the known angle bisectors and $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ their respective half angles. Apply the sine rule to the triangles ABP and CBP to establish

$$ \frac{\sin\beta}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{AP}{BP},\>\>\>
\frac{\sin\beta}{\sin\gamma}=\frac{CP}{BP}$$

Then,

$$ \frac{\sin\gamma}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{AP}{CP}\tag{1}$$

Let $\theta_1=\angle ADP$ and $\theta_2=\angle CDP$. Apply the sine rule to the triangles ADP and CDP,

$$ \frac{\sin\theta_1}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{AP}{DP},\>\>\>
\frac{\sin\theta_2}{\sin\gamma}=\frac{CP}{DP}$$

Then,

$$ \frac{\sin\theta_1}{\sin\theta_2}
\frac{\sin\gamma}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{AP}{CP}\tag{2}$$

Combine (1) and (2) to get

$$\sin\theta_1=\sin\theta_2$$

Therefore, DP is also the angle bisector.